# VSCode does not detect typos, show nr of references, format C#, suggest API completions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

When I switched to VSCode as my source code editor for Unity some weeks ago, it suggested API completions both for C# and for Unity. It listed the number of references above each variable declaration. It detected typos such as using undefined variables etc...

It does not anymore, none of these nice functionalities work anymore. I beleive it was caused by an extension update, but I did not pay attention at the time. (Anyway, IIUC, extension updates can't be rolled back)

I am running VSCode version 1.7.1 on windows 10 with a.o. following extension: C# for Visual Studio Code (powered by OmniSharp) v1.4.1

At the Unity side, I use the latest (v2.70) version of the [Unity plug-in](https://github.com/dotBunny/VSCode/) maintained by @Reapazor as suggested in [Unity Development with VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/runtimes/unity)

I have setup Unity to use VSCode, and turned on integration with VSCode.

I have no idea why it does (no longer) provide API completion, code checking etc... it even no longer formats the code!

Please advise...

Comment: Please report defects to the related products. SO is not the place to fix the issues. You can of course debug VSCode as it is open sourced.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by thoroughly removing vscode and than reinstalling it.

Sorry for the noise

Comment: It's a good question and a good answer - yeah, VS is a bit of a nightmare with Unity.  When using a Mac, just **don't use it**.  Use BBEdit or whatever your favorite is.

Comment: BTW it goes without saying, just never, ever, ever, ever, ever have anything to do with "monodevelop" on any platform.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on the Unity menu

***Assets > Open C# project In Code***